# mongodb c# set array value in an array

Tags: c#, mongodb

If I have a document with an array that contains arrays, how can I update a field of the second array?

For example, using the MongoDB C# driver, I want to update the field IWantToUpdateThis where the value is John Smith:

```
{
    { 
        "_id" : 0, 
        "Guff" : "Blah", 
        "FirstArray" : [
            { 
                "Blah" : "Guff", 
                "SecondArray" : [
                    { 
                        "IWantToUpdateThis" : "John Smith", 
                        "ButNotThis" : "Not me" 
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "IWantToUpdateThis" : "Will Smith", 
                        "ButNotThis" : "Not me" 
                    }
                ] 
            }
        ]
    } }
```

I tried various options such as:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("FirstArray.SecondArray.IWantToUpdateThis", "John Smith");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("FirstArray.SecondArray.$.IWantToUpdateThis", "My New Value");
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

But I can't seem to update the value.

Edited to add:
The MongoDB version used when the question was posed was v3.2.12-69-g45cc6d2

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out something that works, but I can't believe it is the best solution to the problem:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<Model>("Stuff");
var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq("FirstArray.SecondArray.IWantToUpdateThis", OldValue);
var docIds = collection.Find(filter).Project(x => x.Id).ToList();
foreach (var docId in docIds)
{
    var model = collection.Find(e => e.Id == docId).FirstOrDefault();
    foreach (var first in model.FirstArray)
    {
        foreach(var second in first.SecondArray)
        {
            if (second.IWantToUpdateThis == OldValue)
                second.IWantToUpdateThis = NewValue;
        }
    }
    collection.ReplaceOne(r => r.Id == docId, model);
}
```

If anyone comes up with another answer, it is very likely to be a better way than mine, and I leave this answer here only to show a possible way forward should anyone else find themselves in the same dead end as I.